# Is it possible to set a struct as target for NSTimer

Tags: swift, struct, nstimer

I am trying to set  `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` inside a `struct` but I keep getting the error `Cannot invoke scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval with argument list of type`. When I change the `struct` to a `class` it works fine.

My question is it possible to set a `struct` as the `target` of a `NSTimer`? The API says it should be of type `AnyObject`

```
struct MyTimer{
    init() {
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

and

```
class MyTimer{
    init() {
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** It seems that for a class to be the target of a `scheduledTimer` it has to inherit from NSObject first. A struct could never to that.

Comment: Nope :( `target` is of type `id` which means object. Swift structs are not objects.

Comment: dont forget that in swift structs doesn't pass as reference, they make a copy every time a struct passes to function

Comment: not every language, take example of c++  
`struct myCPPStruct *s = new MyCPPStruct();`
`foo(s)` <--passed by pointer, you can also pass struct by reference in swift using inout, by in default in Swift it is passed by value

Comment: You can however use class functions in an `NSTimer` `extension` like so: https://github.com/radex/SwiftyTimer/blob/master/Src/SwiftyTimer.swift it is not exactly what I meant but it would not require you to make your `class` into a struct.